# How to trigger a notification in Firebase with a condition in Swift?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

I have 2 apps, rider and driver (in the same project in Firebase). If setting up Push Notifications in Firebase, how can I set a condition? For example, if the rider requests a ride, an alert advises the driver to accept or cancel. If the driver accepts the request, a child is added to the database like `ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()`:

```
ref.child("riders").child("RydeAccepted").child(usersname).setValue(data)
```

How would I set it up so that when this happens, a notification is sent to the rider app stating the request has been added or removed?

Comment: Are you actually using Push Notifications for this? It would probably be much easier to just use regular Firebase events. Driver is notified of rider, driver declines (which is written to a node that the rider app is observing) and the rider is alerted.

Comment: @Jay No I am not using it as of yet.  I am trying to think of the best way for each app to get the desired alerts.  How would I do this?

Comment: You would do it like I mentioned in my comment. Driver observers a node that the riders post requests to, and when they accept or decline, it gets posted back to the riders node (which they are observing). That being said, it would probably be best to have a node 'requests' where all drivers are observing and just ignore the ones that aren't for them. There's a 100 ways to do it, so that's two.

Comment: I am new at firebase and swift.  I had a hard time figuring out how to do it the way I got it so far, lol.  So I'm not sure I can figure that out on my own.

Comment: In the future, please post your Firebase structure as text, not images. that way its searchable and we don't have to retype it when answering. You can get the structure as text via the Firebase console - then the three vertical dots in the right corner. Export JSON.

Comment: sorry about that, I will try to do as you suggested thanks for your help anyhow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This possible structure may help and simplify the structure in the question

```
drivers
   -Yuiu9jasjdasd
      name: "driver 1"
   -Huuajwiojiejw
      name: "driver 2"

riders
   -Yij99js9skos
      name: "rider 1"
   -Y090jssiisss
      name: "rider 2"


rider_driver_requests
   -Yuljai8jsid99jsds
      requested_by_rider: "-Yij99js9skos"
      for_driver: "-Yuiu9jasjdasd"
      driver_response: "Pending"
   -Y99mskksmnjndjnsj
      requested_by_rider: "-Y090jssiisss"
      for_driver: "-Huuajwiojiejw"
      driver_response: "Accepted"
```

In the above structure, rider_1 has requested a ride from driver_1, but driver_1 has not responded yet (when they do, the driver_response will change from pending to declined or accepted).

rider_2 has requested a ride from driver_2 and driver two has already accepted.

Both riders and drivers are observing the rider_driver_requests node and will each be notified of additions, changes or remove events in that node.

Before you say 'that node is going to get huge!', the reason I structured it like this is that in the future, a rider may not be requesting a specific driver - they may be requesting drivers in an area.

So all drivers within that area would want to be notified of the request so they would all be observing that node and comparing their current position (long, lat for example) with the position of the rider who requested the ride.